# Problems when looping web scraping with lists

Tags: python, function, selenium

The code works perfectly, but when I add a web site whose domain is not registered, the code stops working. Example: sincoban.com.br.
The idea is that you can fill in some value for domains that are not registered. Any way to resolve this?

```
#Script que coleta todas as informações dos domínios ".br"
sites = []
site = {}

domains = ['terra.com.br','oi.com.br','unidas.com.br','sincoban.com.br']

#scrape elements
ff = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="D:/Programas/gecko/geckodriver.exe")

for domain in domains:

    site = {}

    ff.get('https://www.whois.com/whois/'+ domain)
    html = ff.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

    #Tags de interesse
    list_ = soup.find('div', {'class':'df-block'})
    h = soup.find('div', {'class':'df-block'})

   #names web sites 
    try:
        names = list_
    except:
        names = ""

    names = list_
    registro = []
    for name in names:
        registro.append(name.text.split()[51])
        site['DomainInformation'] = registro
        #print(name)


    #DNS hosting
    try:
        registers = list_
    except:
        registers = ""

    registers = list_
    status = []

    try:
        element = h.text.split().index('published')

    except:
        element = ""

    element = h.text.split().index('published') #elemento de pesquisa
    for register in registers:
        status.append(register.text.split()[element]) #Passa o parâmetro pesquisado
        site['status'] = status
        #print(name)


    #List web sites
    sites.append(site)
```

[image]

Comment: `list_` is not guaranteed to be a list, so you can't iterate over it in these cases.

Comment: It looks like you already have error handling, but you defeat your own purpose. Why do you have `names = list_` in a try/except and also outside it? Why not also check `if names:` which would resolve whether it's`None` or not?

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this problem.